# Is it possible to limit the number of Match Queries inside a Bool Query that contribute to the score?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following Documents:

```
[
{
"name": "Berlin",
"name_english": "Berlin"
},
{
"name": "München",
"name_english": "Munich"
}
]
```

Now I do query 1:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "Munich"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name_english": {
                            "query": "Munich"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I do query 2:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "Berlin"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name_english": {
                            "query": "Berlin"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Query 1 will have a lower score than query 2, because query 2 has 2 hits. My goal now is to have only 1 hit maximum of the fields to contribute to the score. Is that possible somehow? Like "If there is a hit in the first Match Query, dont do the second one".

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution, but maybe it's possible using the [painless script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html), or you another way is you handle it from your application by sending queries in `if..else` conditions.